# Magento duplicating options

Tags: php, magento

I'm generating custom options for products in magento with the following:

```
    $options = array();
    $options = array(
        'title' => 'Select Options',
        'type' => 'radio',
        'is_require' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'values' => array()
    );
    $options['values'][] = array(
        'title' => $customAttributeString,
        'price' => 0.00,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => $uniqueId,
        'sort_order' => '1'
    );

    $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    if(!$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {
        $product->setProductOptions(array($options));
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        $product->save();
    }
```

I have this running in a loop, with a different SKU everytime and when I run my loop once, it generates custom options for the first product just fine, the second product has its own custom options, and the first products custom options, and the third product has custom options for all three, etc.. could anyone give me some insight on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$product->setProductOptions(array($option));
```

Notice, that you're setting not $options but $option (without "s" at the end). Maybe it intersects with some of your variables not shown in code snippet.

Also
    $options = array();
is useless here, just remove it

It would be nicer, if you include iteration cycle and initialization of $customAttributeString, $sku, $uniqueId to you code sample there.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for the late response but as Magento manage the product_option as a Singleton, you need to reset it on each iteration :

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->unsetOptions();
```

Hope this helps.

Guillaume

Comment: Thank you so much for this... was looking everywhere for a solution.

Comment: Thank you! I spend 5 hours, I knew that singleton is the reson just could not find a way I shown!

Comment: Thanks, this really helped a lot, spent a lot of time with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->unsetOptions();
```

Work fine just before the loop iteration

Atif